# How to get any numbers sorted from string variable in Java?

Tags: java

How to get any number like '101010' or '001101' to '111000' in Java?
Following is the code to be used for and edited to attain the output

I tried putting the main logic and assigning values to line2 for output. I used line to fetch input, but it doesn't work!

```
/*NOTE : Class Name should be Main */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> inputByLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                inputByLine.add(line.toString());
            }
            for (String line2 : inputByLine)
                System.out.println(line2);
            isr.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the numbers to be sorted, all the ones to be on the beginning followed by the zeroes.

Comment: if you have those numbers in `String` there is nothing more you need. Just sort that list of `String` and you should get numbers followed by zero at the beginning.

Plus, your code does not show any sign of sorting attempt.

Answer (score 2):

As I have understood, you can count the number of 1's and 0's and according sort them into your final string. (Assuming you are taking only binary numbers as strings - only 1's and 0's).

```
    String numbers="111000111000",result="";
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    int count_1=0,count_0=0;
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length();i++){
        if(numbers.charAt(i)=='1'){
            count_1++;
        }    
        else if(numbers.charAt(i)=='0'){
            count_0++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<count_1;i++)  
        sb.append("1");
    for(int i=0;i<count_0;i++)
        sb.append("0");
    result=sb.toString();
```

If you want to consider other cases too (for example you want to ignore strings if users type decimal numbers or anything) then you can add this line to your code

```
result=(sb.length()==0)?numbers:sb.toString();
```

Here, I have checked whether the StringBuilder is null or not and If it is null that means input doesn't contain only 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 0):

```
String numbers = "0110101";
char[] digits = numbers.toCharArray(); 
Arrays.sort(digits);
String result = new String(digits);
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong with this code. First, `toCharArray` is a method, not a field. Second,`Arrays.sort` sorts in place, so it returns void.

Comment: Thats true. Fast response misstype

Answer (score 0):

```java
public String sort(String input) {
    char tempArray[] = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(tempArray);
    String sortedString = String.valueOf(tempArray); //here the string is sorted "naturrally" with the 0 leading

    //You need to reverse it
    return new StringBuilder(sortedString).reverse().toString();
}
```

Another option is to implement your own Comparator and use it directly.
Hope this helps !